# How to perform a left join and ignoring a default value?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, merge, left-join

Table df1 (a Pandas dataframe):

```
      id1    type    cat
0       1       a      0
1       1       b      0
2       2       a      8
3       2       a      9
```

Table df2:

```
      id2    type    cat
0       0       a      8
1       0       a      9
2       1       a      8
3       1       a      9
4       2       a      8
5       3       a      9
6       4       b      7
7       5       b      8
```

I am performing a left join:

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left')
```

I am again doing this with Pandas, but I could use SQL, and I get:

```
      id1    type    cat     id2
0       1       a      0     NaN
1       1       b      0     NaN
2       2       a      8     0.0
3       2       a      8     1.0
4       2       a      8     2.0
5       2       a      9     0.0
6       2       a      9     1.0
7       2       a      9     3.0
```

What I want, though, is to treat the `0` in the `cat` column of df1 like a wildcard, like it is including ALL categories. It doesn't have an expression and should therefore be excluded from the merge.

In this example the result would include all rows from df2, because only the `type` column would have to match.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a simple solution for that, but one thing you can do is to separately prepare dataframe with wildcard join and concat them at the end:

```
merged1 = pd.merge(df1[df1['cat']!=0, df2, how='left')
df1_tmp = df1[df1['cat']==0].drop('cat', axis=1)
df1_tmp['key'] = 0
df2['key'] = 0
merged2 = df1_tmp.merge(df2, on='key', how='outer')
merged = pd.concat(merged1, merged2)
```